# Laravel 5 date Format value

Tags: laravel, date, format, missing-data

I would like to know why my code is not working.
I have my model Organigramme i want to calculate with a function the age between two dates:

```
public function getAncienneteAttribute()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();

    $date_dentree = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->date_dentree);

        return $now->diffInYears($date_dentree);

}
```

But I'm faced this error: Data missing
Someone can help me please.

Comment: which line does the error occur?

Comment: I suspect it occurs on  `$date_dentree = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->date_dentree);`, are you sure `$this->date_dentree` is `/d/m/Y` format?

Comment: I added an answer regarding your problem. On another note, I [advise you not to use Accessors](https://laraveldaily.com/the-biggest-problem-with-eloquent-accessors-magic/), they are bad design and result in hard-to-understand code. You can just create a custom (getter) function in your model like `getAnciennete` and call it like `->getAnciennete()` on your Model object, no magic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$this->date_dentree` format is not matching the format you passed to `Carbon::createFromFormat`, it is probably the default format so try the code below:

```
public function getAncienneteAttribute()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    return $now->diffInYears(new Carbon($this->date_dentree));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$date_dentree = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->date_dentree);
$diffYears = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInYears($date_dentree );

//\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->date)->format('Y-m-d')

$dbDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2020-05-10');
$diffYears = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInYears($dbDate);
```

Comment: Hi Team, The problem was that I had a null value in on of my date_dentree columns. I have changed that and all works nice. so, this code public function getAncienneteAttribute()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();

    $date_dentree = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->date_dentree);

        return $now->diffInYears($date_dentree);

} works for me.  THANK TO ALL